# Trying to integrate an HTTP GET request in my MS-Access database program

Tags: vba, http, ms-access, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

I want to import data from Anedot, a credit card processing firm, using a HTTP GET request from an MS Access program. Anedot uses a RESTful API and has provided help on there website: https://anedot.com/api/v2

I want to do this with VBA, and associate the import with a button on an MS Access form. I've read that this only possible with XML. Do I create the XML file with VBA?

I'd greatly appreciate some background information on how to get this done, as most of it is flying over my head. I don't really know where to begin and I'm having trouble finding anything useful on google.

So far I've realized I'll need to reference their API via a URL link (which they provide), and that I'll have to authorize my account using my username and a token ID. But how can I do this in VBA?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

First of all try to make a request to API using basic authorization. Take a look at the below code as the example:

```
Sub Test()

    ' API URL from https://anedot.com/api/v2
    sUrl = "https://api.anedot.com/v2/accounts"
    ' The username is the registered email address of your Anedot account
    sUsername = "mymail@example.com"
    ' The password is your API token
    sPassword = "1e56752e8531647d09ec8ab20c311ba928e54788"
    sAuth = TextBase64Encode(sUsername & ":" & sPassword, "us-ascii") ' bXltYWlsQGV4YW1wbGUuY29tOjFlNTY3NTJlODUzMTY0N2QwOWVjOGFiMjBjMzExYmE5MjhlNTQ3ODg=
    ' Make the request
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", sUrl, False
        .SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & sAuth
        .Send
        Debug.Print .ResponseText
        Debug.Print .GetAllResponseHeaders
    End With

End Sub

Function TextBase64Encode(sText, sCharset) ' 05 10 2016
    Dim aBinary
    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Type = 2 ' adTypeText
        .Open
        .Charset = sCharset ' "us-ascii" for bytes to unicode
        .WriteText sText
        .Position = 0
        .Type = 1 ' adTypeBinary
        aBinary = .Read
        .Close
    End With
    With CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM").CreateElement("objNode")
        .DataType = "bin.base64"
        .NodeTypedValue = aBinary
        TextBase64Encode = Replace(Replace(.Text, vbCr, ""), vbLf, "")
    End With
End Function
```

Put your credentials to `sUsername` and `sPassword` variables, choose the appropriate URL from [API help page](https://anedot.com/api/v2) and put it to `sURL`. Then you can parse JSON response from the server (currently you will see the response for `/v2/accounts` request in Immediate window).

Answer (score 1):

It's a fairly lengthy question to be honest, but lets start with some code to get you going.

This Class Module ("`clsXMLHttpMonitor`") should help:

```
Option Explicit


Dim XMLHttpReq As MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP

Dim RequestedVar As String
Dim P As Object

Public Sub Initialize(ByVal uXMLHttpRequest As Object, Optional RequestedValue As String = "")
   RequestedVar = RequestedValue
   Set XMLHttpReq = uXMLHttpRequest
End Sub

Sub ReadyStateChangeHandler()
    If XMLHttpReq.ReadyState = 4 Then
        If XMLHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
            'Process the response here
            Debug.Print "200 recieved"
            Set P = JSON.parse(XMLHttpReq.responseText)
        Else
            If XMLHttpReq.Status = 404 Then
                'Handle it
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Function returnResponseHeaders() As String
returnResponseHeaders = XMLHttpReq.getAllResponseHeaders
XMLHttpReq.Send
End Function

Function returnFullText() As String
If XMLHttpReq.ReadyState = 4 Then
    If XMLHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
        returnFullText = XMLHttpReq.responseText
    Else
        returnFullText = "-1"
    End If
Else
    returnFullText = ""
End If
End Function

End Function
```

Use it like this:

```
Set XMLHttpReq = New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP
Set XMLHttpMon = New clsXMLHttpMonitor
XMLHttpMon.Initialize XMLHttpReq
XMLHttpReq.OnReadyStateChange = XMLHttpMon
XMLHttpReq.Open "POST", URL, True
XMLHttpReq.Send strPayload
```

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to request a Json response from a URL, you can study the Json modules here for a full implementation that collects the Json response in a collection,  which you then can use in your code or save to a table. See the *demo* module for examples:

[VBA.CVRAPI](https://github.com/CactusData/VBA.CVRAPI)